# Checked Another hidden radio Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

**hello**,

I'm trying to select hidden radio `input` when selecting another one

```
<div class="questions">
<div class="questions_title">
    <span> Q : What Are you doing now ?</span>
</div>                       
<div class="answers">           
  <script>
      $('#answerid_').on('checked', function() {
         $('#degres_').prop('checked', true);
         return false;
      });
  </script>

  <div class="field">
   <input type="radio" value="1915" id="answerid_1" name="answerid_1" class="required">
   <input type="hidden" value="0" id="degres_1" name="degres_1">
   <span class="questions_label">Working. </span>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
   <input type="radio" value="1916" id="answerid_2" name="answerid_1">
   <input type="hidden" value="1" id="degres_2" name="degres_1">
   <span class="questions_label">Playing.</span>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
   <input type="radio" value="1917" id="answerid_3" name="answerid_1">
   <input type="hidden" value="2" id="degres_3" name="degres_1">
   <span class="questions_label">not Sleeping </span>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
   <input type="radio" value="1918" id="answerid_4" name="answerid_1">
   <input type="hidden" value="3" id="degres_4" name="degres_1">
   <span class="questions_label">Nothing.</span>
  </div>

</div>
```

I need => When selecting any answer the according next hidden `degree` would be checked too

Comment: after use the folowing code

`$('[id^=answerid_]').on('change', function() { $(this).siblings('[id^=degres_]').prop('checked', true); //alert($(this).siblings('[id^=degres_]').prop('checked')); return false; });`

and changing hidden input to anther radio **because  it not workin hidden input** and by adding 

`style="margin-left: -16px; position: absolute;"` 

for every answer input it work and it show as 1 button 

`but in question 21 it's not select degree button`

Answer (score 1):

You can't check a hidden-type input. However, you can check a radio-type invisible input (with `display:none` style).

Comment: yes i know this, and i have add comment above that i solve this issue but there is another error appear :)

`but in question 21 it's not select degree button`

Answer (score 0):

You need wild card to attach event and change event.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/tTpCu/)**

```
$('[id^=answerid_]').on('change', function() {
        $(this).next(':hidden').prop('checked', true);
        return false;
});
```

Instead of using check of hidden I would suggest you to set the value of hidden field.

```
$(this).next(':hidden').val("true");
```

Answer (score 0):

it should be..

```
 $('[id^=answerid_]').on('change', function() {
    $(this).next().prop('checked', true);
    return false;
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

***JS CODE***

```
$('[id^=answerid_]').on('change', function() {
        $(this).siblings('[id^=degres_]').prop('checked', true);
        alert($(this).siblings('[id^=degres_]').prop('checked'));
   return false;
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tTpCu/1/)

Comment: thank you every one i tried to use the folowing code
`$('[id^=answerid_]').on('change', function() { $(this).siblings('[id^=degres_]').prop('checked', true); //alert($(this).siblings('[id^=degres_]').prop('checked')); return false; });`
but in hidden input it not work but by adding 
`style="margin-left: -16px; position: absolute;"` 
for every answer input it work and it show as 1 button `but in question 21 it's not select degree button`

Answer (score 0):

You can't check a hidden-type input. it is expecting a value, so the value could be 1 if previous is cecked or 0 if not checked.

Comment: yes i know this, and i have add comment above that i solve this issue but there is another error appear :)

`but in question 21 it's not select degree button`

Answer (score 0):

after use the folowing code

`$('[id^=answerid_]').on('change', function() { $(this).siblings('[id^=degres_]').prop('checked', true); //alert($(this).siblings('[id^=degres_]').prop('checked')); return false; });`

and changing hidden input to another radio because it now work and by adding

`style="margin-left: -16px; position: absolute;"`

for every answer input to be above degrees radio it work successfully.

**but in the last question it's not work or check degree input :(**